# using pathlib instead of os for identifying file and changing

Tags: python, pathlib

I have tried to do the below using pathlib instaed of os.

```
import sys
import os     

folder = sys.argv[1]
newfolder = sys.argv[2] 

for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    img = Image.open(f'{folder}{filename}')
    img.save(f'{newfolder}{filename}','png')
    print('All Done')

#for path in Path(folder).iterdir():
    #if path.is_file() and path.suffix == '.jpg':
        #img = Image.open(f'{folder}{path}')
        #img.save(f'{newfolder}{path}','png')
```

Tried this but not working...

Comment: Path(newfolder).mkdir(exist_ok = True)

Comment: i forgot to mention this line  Path(newfolder).mkdir(exist_ok = True)  for creating a new folder.

Comment: But how to do this in using pathlib alone

Answer (score 1):

Change `img.save(f'{newfolder}{filename}', 'png')` to `img.save(f'{newfolder}{filename}.png')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to merge multiple paths.

```py
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join('folder', 'filename')
folder\\filename
>>> os.path.join('folder\folder2', 'filename')
folder\\folder2\\filename
```

Try this:

```py
import sys
import os     
folder = sys.argv[1]
newfolder = sys.argv[2] 
   
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    img = Image.open(os.path.join(folder, filename))
    img.save(os.path.join(newfolder, filename),'png')
print('All Done')
```