# Pathlib: change end of file name

Tags: python, pathlib

I am trying to iterate through a directory, do something to each of the files and then save a new file with a different name similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68972637/using-pathlib-instead-of-os-for-identifying-file-and-changing), but I am looking for a solution using pathlib. I am just not sure how to add the desired ending to the end of the file name

```
movie_dir = pathlib.Path("/movies")
save_dir = pathlib.Path("/corrected_movies")


for dir in movie_dir.iterdir():
    for movie_path in dir.iterdir():
        save_path = save_dir / movie_path # want to add _corrected.avi to end of file name
```

Comment: so `/movies` has nested subdirectories?  be careful here, because `movie_path` will be an absolute path and `save_dir / movie_path` will just resolve again to `movie_path`.

Comment: hmm okay, then I guess I also need to extract the file name from the directory and not the absolute path. There are too many pending edits right now but will update the question shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, assuming your `movie_path` paths have the correct extension already, you can do something like:

```
save_path = save_dir / move_path.with_stem(movie_path.stem + "_corrected")
```

If they don't have the same extension, then you can add:

```
save_path = save_dir / move_path.with_stem(movie_path.stem + "_corrected").with_suffix(".avi")
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments, be careful that `movie_path` is going to be an absolute path! Do a dry run to see. If that is the case, and you could simply extract the `.name`, so:

```
save_path = (
    save_dir / move_path.with_stem(movie_path.stem + "_corrected").with_suffix(".avi").name
)
```

Although, given your situation and not having to keep the original extension, I think this can just be simplified to:

```
save_path = save_dir / (movie_path.stem + "_corrected.avi")
```

Comment: They do not have the same extension. Part of the loop changes the type of file.

Comment: @keenan ok, then use `.with_suffix` as well, see my edit

Comment: how would I extract the file name from the absolute path?

Comment: @keenan already added that... with `.name`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question here : [Adding another suffix to a path that already has a suffix with pathlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49380572/adding-another-suffix-to-a-path-that-already-has-a-suffix-with-pathlib)

If you use pathlib3x : `append_suffix` function

or you can do like that :

```
save_path = (save_dir / pathlib.Path(str(movie_path) + "_corrected.avi"))
```

you can put this little code in a function to simulate `append_suffix`, like for example :

```
def append_suffix(path):
    return pathlib.Path(str(path) + "_corrected.avi")

save_path = save_dir / append_suffix(movie_path)
```

If your movies have already a .avi extension, just add a slice operation (or something similar) :

```
def append_suffix(path):
    return pathlib.Path(str(path)[:-4] + "_corrected.avi")
```